# RESTEasy Enable GZIP Support?

Tags: java, web-services, tomcat, gzip, resteasy

The documentation for RESTEasy says that in addition to annotating your server endpoint with the "@GZIP" annotation, you need to make a file called "javax.ws.rs.ext.Providers" available in the classpath of your runtime environment and include the classname "org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.interceptors.encoding.GZIPEncodingInterceptor" in the file.

I've done all of the above, but the response coming back from the server is NOT compressed, even though the response "Content-Encoding" header is "gzip" (i.e. the response body is plain text/json, despite what the header says).

The javax.ws.rs.ext.Providers file is definitely in my WEB-INF/classes folder in the .war and in the app folder when deployed to Tomcat, but RESTEasy is ignoring it.

So, is there something I'm missing?  Does anyone have this working?

**EDIT: Okay, I discovered that RESTEasy is actually looking for the full path "META-INF/services/javax.ws.rs.ext.Providers", so I had to create that folder path plus file in my resources folder.  And yes, that is confusing, since there is already a META-INF folder in the .war archive; however, putting the "services" sub-folder and "javax.ws.rs.ext.Providers" file in that META-INF folder does NOT work.  Sigh.**

Comment: Did you use a packet sniffer to determine that is not compressed?

Comment: Yes, I used TCPMon to examine the traffic and determined that the traffic was uncompressed JSON, despite the fact that the HTTP header claims it was gzip.

Answer (score 3):

I got it working & I hope this will help you in resolving the same. The trick is to have this within the WEB-INF/classes. What I did was to have   ***javax.ws.rs.ext.Providers*** in the location: ***/WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/services*** & voila it started working.

The reason for this is to do with the classloader reference that it has in the code trying to search for this file. I am using tomcat. But if you are using JBoss or any other application / web server, the classloading mechanisms might vary based on the container implementation. So figure out which is the best location for your server.